# android : Timeoutexception while waiting for mails using Javamails

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, imap, timeoutexception

I am using Javamail apis to read gmail / yahoo in my app. I have a timertask which which spwans threads to fetch mails periodically.  It is working fine for gmail. For Yahoo i am getting a timeout exception as below.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore.finalize() timed out after 15 seconds
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:686)
at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:124)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:96)
at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:95)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:60)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:280)
at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.command(Protocol.java:313)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.examine(IMAPProtocol.java:864)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.close(IMAPFolder.java:1329)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.close(IMAPFolder.java:1263)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.cleanup(IMAPStore.java:1494)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.close(IMAPStore.java:1387)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.finalize(IMAPStore.java:1428)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:188)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:171)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I didnt get the logic why it is happening. What i could see is that yahoo is taking relatively more time to respond than gmail. But i am not clear how this delay is resulting in calling finalizedaemon. Can anyone explain whats could be actually happening and is there a way to solve this issue

Parts of my code is here .
This is what done by the function called from the thread . Only the major lines are given here as the function is huge. This exception is random. Sometime mails are read successfully. So i dont suspect the code.

```
store = session.getStore(sProtocol);
                        store.connect(acct.sIncomingHost, sUserOrEmail, acct.sPassword);
.....
folder = store.getFolder("foldername");
folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);


            Message[] msgs = null;



                    msgs = folder.getMessages(index,
                            count);
```

Comment: Can you show that how/where you use the javamail class.

Comment: i have added few lines of my code

Comment: Your code is wrong; you're letting go of something and if garbage is collected before that object is done, the object is finalized and then you get the error you see. Perhaps the variables that reference the javamail object graph are local to a function, and that function returns?

Comment: Could you please explain more . In my service , i have a timer task for each account. Now when the timer runs , it calls a function. Yes the variables are local to this function. Can you explain "the object is finalized" . which object. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you closing the Store when you're done with it?  The finalize method is called when the object is garbage collected.  If you close the Store when you're done with it, before you destroy all references and it turns into garbage, then the finalize method should be quite fast.  But if the Store is left open, the finalize method will try to close it, which requires interacting with the server, which might not be fast.

Comment: I was not explicitly calling folder.close / store.close . So finalize was calling it and it was leading to timeout for yahoo mails. When i added these as explicit calls , there are no more exceptions. Thanks a lot for the response